# Ableton: Pressing solo button on audio track mutes all tracks, including the one I am trying to solo

Tags: ableton-live, audio, solos

In my Ableton Live 10 project right now, I have both midi and audio tracks. When I press the solo button on my midi tracks it behaves as I expect - the solo'd track is audible and all the others are muted.

When I press 'solo' on one of my audio tracks, however, I hear nothing - all of the other tracks are muted but the track in question is muted too.

How can I hear the output of just one of my audio tracks?

If it matters, the output of the midi tracks is routed to Master, and the audio tracks are routed to a mix of A and B sends, which then route to Master.

Comment: You have to solo the sends also. The sends are being muted and that stops the flow of audio to master.

Comment: This does not happen to me in Live 9. Live can figure out the routing automatically and I do not have to solo the sends. Is Audio To set to Sends Only on your audio track, or how have you routed it to the sends only and not master?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the issue could be but here's a process of elimination to help you troubleshoot your issue:
Try a minimalistic test. Create a new project with just two tracks, one midi and one audio. Record something simple into both. Then test the audio track's solo button and see if the issue still happens. If it does happen then your installation of Ableton may have an issue.
If it doesn't happen, however, there has to be something in the original project causing the issue. At that point you can make a copy of the original project, open it up, then delete half of your tracks and test and see if the issue persists. If it doesn't it means the issue was related to one of the tracks removed. If it still happens, try removing half of the tracks left, repeat the process.
If in effect you get to a point where the issue doesn't happen because of removing tracks then take note of which tracks you removed. Go back to the original project and compare the settings for those tracks you took note of to default settings for new audio and midi tracks and see if you can spot a difference that may be causing the issue.